# docker containers are not communicating as expected

Tags: .net-core, docker-compose, sphinx, docker-network

I have an interesting problem that I'm trying to resolve.

We are trying to create a multi-container microservice consisting of a dotnet core API container and a sphinx search container. The sphinx container builds its indexes off a network SQL Server DB.

I have successfully tested the containers separately:

1. From a .NET v4.5 version of the API I can query the sphinx container and get results.
2. Using the API container pointed at a sphinx service running on my local machine I also get results.

Where it gets interesting is when I run the 2 containers using docker-compose. I can see the query arriving in the sphinx container, but no results are returned.

So I know the individual components work correctly.  And they are definitely able to talk to each other. But for some reason the data is not being returned.

I'm not sure if posting the dockerfiles or docker-compose would be of any use, but just in case here's the docker-compose.

```
version: '2'
services:
    sphinx3:
        build: sphinx/.
        container_name: sphinx3

    api:
        build: api/.
        container_name: api
        ports:
            - "52707:80"
        depends_on:
            - sphinx3
```

Sphinx version is 3.0.3-facc3fb
Sphinx image is built using ubuntu:16.04

API image is built using aspnetcore-build:2.0

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Have you tried to restart docker service? ( `systemctl restart docker` ) Had it once that it sent request to wrong container after multiple docker-compose up/down.

Comment: I have restarted docker, as well as tried @nati 's idea of using v3 with a network specified.  But still I get no data from the sphinx container. I can see the request being received in sphinx, just no data is returned.

Comment: If you map the port of sphinx to your host and try to query it from outside this works?

Comment: Yeah. Container A can call outside correctly. Outside can call Container B correctly. But Container A gets an empty response from B.  I'm wondering if it's an encoding issue between the image types since A is a microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 image and B is a ubuntu image

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'aliases', I could able to talk between containers using there aliases.

PS: I am using the docker-compose of version 3, where you have to specify a network to hold the containers.

Comment: I think in the end it was an issue with cached images on my machine. I did a `docker system prune` and everything started working...